# Personalized sub-domain URLs

Tags: redirects, url-rewriting, subdomain

Most of the SaaS companies, some social networking, and blog services (like Wordpress.com and blogger) create a personalized sub-domain for each user, e.g. username.website.com

What is the general practice for doing this. Do most of them really create a sub-domain or do they add some kind of URL redirects/routes for achieving this (assume Apache with mod_rewrite support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually just wild card DNS along with server side programming that checks the hostname.